# What method should I use to parse csv files in bash

Tags: bash, csv

I'm trying to parse numbers in a csv file which are all in one single line and delimited by a semicolon.

This is what I get after this command
    cat Input.csv

```
1;3;2;1;4;2;4;5;3;2;5;2;7;3;9;14;5;12;3;2;15;4;10;2;5;3;7;8;11;2;9;12;5;1;11;8;3;4;9;13;13;12;1;12;11;4;7;11;10;9
```

I've tried using while IFS=";" read , but since the whole input is in the same line, it's only possible if i create 50 variables which is not particularly practical.

The task i need to complete is to simulate a FIFO scheduling algorithm, hence I first need to read all values from the csv file which I'm currently stuck.
Do I use while or for or other method ?

Comment: maybe substitute ";" to "\n", redirect it into a new file and loop through each line of it?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't, as a field could contain quoted commas that `bash` simply can't deal with using the simple tools it provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is repeating a deleted but correct answer

```
IFS=";" read -r -a array < Input.csv
declare -p array
```

That reads the first line of the input file, splits on semi-colons and stores into the **array** variable named `array`.

The `-r` option for the read command means any backslashes in the input are handled as literal characters, not as introducing an escape sequence.
The `-a` option reads the words from the input into an array named by the gived variable name.

At a bash prompt, type `help declare` and `help read`.

Also find a bash tutorial that talks about the effect of `IFS` on the `read` command, for example [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)
The [bash tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) has tons of resources.